# Two days that all.js (Facebook SDK) is randomly not loading

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

we are experience since yesterday the "FB is not defined" error, caused by Facebook not serving all.js, which is the core Javascript SDK file.

Looking at the NET tab in Firebug or Chrome developer tools, I can see the get on all.js failing.

After a few page refreshes, it works correctly, then 10 minutes later is again not serving the file.

Is it a Facebook issue? Apparently we have no other network error, and we are not behind a proxy. Anyone else experiencing it? Facebook status page is not reporting any problem, and I cannot find anything recent on Google.

Is it "normal"? like Facebook limiting gets based on some "cap" or anything similar?

Comment: We are still experiencing the problem. The GET to connect.facebook.com simply dies there. We have no other problem of any sort on all the rest of the internet. Anybody else have (or have had) this problem? Any plausible reason?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? No, seriously, have tried same thing on another server or from different computers?

Comment: @webarto yes, we are 4 developers, all experiencing the same problem, also from different locations.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no problem with protocol substitution. Try to replace //connect.facebook.com/en_US/all.js with https://connect.facebook.com/en_US/all.js

Comment: Also you must understand that most ISP providers uses proxies, so you cant know this for sure. try to ad ?_=timestamp to the url. And also check it from another IP from another ISP.

Comment: @Creotiv, `//` in from of url are simple shorthand to _current_ URI scheme. What you suggesting is same wrong URL that will not load no matter which scheme you choose.

Comment: Have you tried some other tools to check what's going on? I mean `curl` oe even `traceroute`. What "guy" who manage "networking stuff" say on this? Can you `dig` the `connect.facebook.net`?

Comment: // - Not working when you open page localy(and i know how this must wokr :) ). Also there can be bug in browser. So i just check this.

Comment: I think this is you local ISP provider problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run into this same issue before.  It was something that I could never really pin down but it was believed to be an issue with Facebook.  My solution was to grab a copy of all.js and serve it up locally.

Comment: This is a fine solution.. I do always do this, only thing we have to take care is whenever there is an update to js sdk (all.js) we have to download that to our local server and i think this aint going to be hard task ;-)

Comment: Hi wafflestomper, I ended up using an (horrible) sync load of a local copy of all.js in case all.js from Facebook failed to load with the common async system. Unfortunately, this happens after the original request timed out, which means after quite a long time .. it is however a valid solution during development.

Answer (score 2):

Your description sounds like a network issue, but if you are loading the SDK asynchronously and trying the use the FB object before it has fully loaded, it will cause this error and may also stop attempting to load the all.js due to the Javascript error.

To resolve this, put all references to the FB object inside of the window.fbAsyncInit function seen on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

This may not be your issue, but that is almost always the solution when I see that error.

Answer (score -1):

You must add the Facebook SDK all.js on the bottom of your page.
Before the Facebook SDK, you must add `<div id="fb-root"></div>`

After this load, you can call the function FB.

The call of Facebook SDK must be with the document.protocol HTTPS or HTTP.

Good luck !

Comment: Hi Pierre, placing the script down the page will speed up loading, but not affect its load cycle AFAIK.